# Don't clear the custom flag message when dismissing the window

Tags: feature-request, design, flags

It has happened with me a lot of times, when the text I wrote was cleared after a flag dialog was dismissed.

> [image]

Please, don't clear the message, when window dismisses.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... Treat the cause, not the symptom...

Comment: I have no idea what the intent is behind the long quotation box that's empty—and which links to a picture of an empty box.

Comment: @RobertLongson, I think this proposal differs as that one asks to prevent modal closing and this one asks to restore the text when the modal is reopened.